# How to enable verbose logging in non standalone wiremock

Tags: wiremock

I see that there are instructions on enabling verbose logging for wiremock when running it in standalone fashion at http://wiremock.org/running-standalone.html (see --verbose).

How do I enable the same when starting it from a java code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

WireMock uses SLF4J.  Set the level of the category `com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock` to `TRACE`.  Consult the [SLF4J manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) to find out how to accomplish this in your case.

Answer (score 26):

If you're using a JUnit Rule, you can set the notifier to verbose mode like this:

```java
@Rule
public WireMockRule serviceMock = new WireMockRule(new WireMockConfiguration().notifier(new Slf4jNotifier(true)));
```

Comment: Somehow this stopped working for me (probably version upgrade). I have replaced it with http://wiremock.org/docs/configuration/#notification-logging `.notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(true))`.

Comment: I can confirm `Slf4jNotifier` working along with logback appender `com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock` set to to DEBUG. `wiremock-jre8:2.27.2`.

Answer (score 2):

Set Notifier to ConsoleNotifier(true).

```
WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(WireMockConfiguration.options().port(8080).httpsPort(443)
.notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(true)).extensions(new ResponseTemplateTransformer(true)));
```